# Compute the Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I'm trying to compute the Frobenius norm of $L^{-1}$ where 
$$L^{-1}= I + N + N^2 + ... + N^{n-1}$$
and $N$ is strictly lower triangular.

Can anyone suggest some way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply construct $L$ from $N$ directly instead of evaluating it as a sum? I also assume that $L$ is unit lower triangular?

Comment: yes. L is a unit lower triangular matrix and $L$ is actually given by $L  = I - N$ but I don't think that form would help in computing the Frobenius norm of $L^{-1}$, so I tried to write $L^{-1}$ in the above form..

Comment: It would certainly be easier to evaluate the norm directly by forming the inverse of $L$ than by using the sum, unless there's a really good reason for not to do so which probably is not the case.

Comment: But L is only given by $L=I-N$ where L is unit lower triangular.
How do can I find the Frobenius norm of $L^{-1}$?